# How to create calculated columns in SQL with sql-window functions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi, window-functions

So I am working on this solution that involves fetching input of 3 columns say 'Year', 'Month' and 'Spend' and use them to create another column 'Year Total' using logic that imitates SQL-window functions. For example, I need the following table given first three columns are editable,

```
|------------|-------|--------|----------|
|   Year     |Month  |  Spend |Year Total|
|------------|-------|--------|----------|
|    2018    |   Jan |  10    |   55     |
|    2018    |   Feb |  20    |   55     |
|    2018    |   Oct |  25    |   55     |
|    2019    |   Jan |  15    |   120    |
|    2019    |   Aug |  60    |   120    |
|    2019    |   Nov |  45    |   120    |
|------------|-------|--------|----------|
```

But calculating this in the frontend and on the fly is making the solution very slow. Hence I am trying to move this calculation to the backend in the SQL table using calculated columns. Basically, data will be written to the backend(SQL), columns calculated and re-read to show in frontend.

I have looked around a bit, only to find that windows functions cannot be used in calculated columns in SQL. Also, **note that stored procedures are not allowed in the solution.**

Can anyone suggest how to do this, or even if this is possible at all?

Note that frontend is Powerapps/Power BI

Comment: Can you explain why year total 2018 is 55 and not 160?

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake while adding rows! Last two rows are for 2019. Edited the question.

Comment: *move this calculation to the backend* = put the window function in a view. Calculated column can only be based on columns from the same row, not across rows.

Comment: I see dnoeth. Are you suggesting that I write back to my SQL table but read from the view?

Comment: How large is the table?

Comment: Hi @RADO , the Total number of rows is ~100K and 42 Columns with the possibility of data growing by 5 folds(row wise).

Comment: @ChinmoyJyotiKathar - for such small data size, it's very strange that this calculation is slow. Power BI is very efficient at aggregations  - your calculation should be nearly instantaneous. Something is not right either with the data model or calculation formulas.

Answer (score 1):

'using logic that imitates SQL-window functions' why?

You just need a join to a sub query which groups by year.

```
select t.* , s.sumspend
from <table> t
join (select year, sum(spend) sumspend from <table> group by year) s
on s.year = t.year;
```

Comment: Hi P.Salmon, thank you for your answer. The problem is that the frontend application(PowerApps) can only read data from SQL server as is, we cannot specify a query when importing data. So, I will need to actually persist this data in the SQL table. Plus stored procedures are not allowed in the solution as I've already mentined in the question. Do you see any workaround to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a view:

```
create view v_t as
    select t.* ,
           sum(spend) over (partition by year) as year_spend
    from t;
```

Window functions are not allowed in generated columns.

SQL Server allows window functions in updatable views, so you will be able to modify the other columns.  You will need to reload the table whenever a change is made, to get the updated data.